# I m receving signature mismatch exception when I try to send http request to aws dynamodb using low-level api (calculating signature by myself)

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I want  to send an HTTP request to AWS DynamoDB without using the AWS SDK in a Salesforce B2C Commerce Cartridge. I've followed the AWS DynamoDB Low-Level API documentation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.LowLevelAPI.html

and Signature Version 4 documentation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html#example-signature-calculations

to construct the request manually. However, I'm encountering an "InvalidSignatureException" with error message :The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.'

could anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong

here is my canonical request

```
const payloadObject = {
TableName: "tableName",
ReturnConsumedCapacity: "TOTAL"
}

const payload = JSON.stringify(payloadObject);
const date = new Date().toISOString().replace(/[:\-]|\.\d{3}/g, '');
const shortDate = date.substring(0, 8);
const payloadHash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(payload).digest('hex');

const canonicalRequest = [
'POST',
'/',
'',
'action=scan',
'content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.0',
'host:dynamodb.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com',
'x-amz-content-sha256:' + payloadHash,
'x-amz-date:' + date,
'x-amz-target:DynamoDB_20120810.Scan',
'',
'content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-target,
payloadHash
].join('\n');

const canonicalRequestHash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(canonicalRequest).digest('hex');
```

output of this canonicalRequest is

```
POST
/

action=scan
content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.0
host:dynamodb.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:4aabc25ba680a6fe0d0cadc9754a0b249b7809904c2f495b1e28ffcea826c347
x-amz-date:20231230T095237Z
x-amz-target:DynamoDB_20120810.Scan,

content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-target
4aabc25ba680a6fe0d0cadc9754a0b249b7809904c2f495b1e28ffcea826c347
```

here is my StringToSign

```
const stringToSign = [
'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
date,
shortDate + '/' + region + '/dynamodb/aws4_request',
canonicalRequestHash
].join('\n');
```

output of string to sign is

```
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20231230T095543Z
20231230/eu-west-2/dynamodb/aws4_request
2ca2fff7661d28aca561e03f48d80d53beed6d27d4422838e60ff3b006ef0f8c
```

and that is how I m calculating signature as described in documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html#example-signature-calculations)

```
const dateKey = crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'AWS4' + secretKey).update(shortDate).digest();
const dateRegionKey = crypto.createHmac('sha256', dateKey).update(region).digest();
const dateRegionServiceKey = crypto.createHmac('sha256', dateRegionKey).update('dynamodb').digest();
const signInKey = crypto.createHmac('sha256', dateRegionServiceKey).update('aws4_request').digest();


const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', signInKey).update(stringToSign).digest('hex);
```

finally that is how I construct my authorization header

```
const AuthorizationHeader = `AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=${accessKey}/${shortDate}/${region}/dynamodb/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=${signature}`;
```

output of this code is

```
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=*********/20231230/eu-west-2/dynamodb/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=a9043338dbb2fd574e34a0b4ffac4a291e5c7c257c50775fa76746ca8438e90b
```

after creating required parameters this how I m sending request

```
axios.post('https://dynamodb.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com?Action=Scan', payload, {
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0',
    'Host': 'dynamodb.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com',
    'X-Amz-Content-SHA256': payloadHash,
    'X-Amz-Date': date,
    'X-Amz-Target': 'DynamoDB_20120810.Scan',
    'Authorization': AuthorizationHeader
}
}
```

after all I m getting this response from call

```
{
 __type: 'com.amazon.coral.service#InvalidSignatureException',
 message: 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you 
 provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service 
 documentation for details.'
}
```

Comment: Double check your credentials key matches exactly and that escape characters didn't omit anything.

Comment: @LeeroyHannigan Hi Leeroy thx for reply, I am able to send request through postman so I thought it would be a good idea to see if I m creating correct signature. I got the hash value of the payload and time stamp from postman request and when I calculate signature with those values signature are matching. so this means calculations are correct right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my url querystring that I used in axios post, does not match the querystring I provided in canonical string. also there is unnecessary empty line between "/" and "action=scan" parameters in canonicalRequest

in my canonicalString querystring was "action=scan"
but as you can see in my axios url it is "https://dynamodb.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com?Action=Scan"

I changed url query string to "https://dynamodb.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com?action=scan" and it worked